# Solving a minimax path problem with some constraints

Tags: algorithm, path, max, minimax

I have a problem where an undirected graph with positive weights are given. There are N vertices and I need to get the minimum of the maximum weight between 2 vertices in a path from all possible paths from vetex 1 to N. However the total weight of these possible paths cannot be more than T.

I realised this is a minimax path problem, so I could construct a minimum spanning tree from the graph and from there, I could get the min-max weight of the paths. But how can I construct the minimum spanning tree with the constraint that the total weight from 1 to N cannot be more than T?

[image: Example graph]

Eg. In the picture, only 1256 and 1356 are possible paths if T is 13. Path 1456 is not considered because the total weight adds up to 14.

And between 1256 and 1356, the edge 35 of weight 7 is the minimax weight of the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming positive edge weights, you could solve this in O((m + n log n) log m) time by doing binary search over which of the m edges is the minimum maximum. The binary search requires O(log m) iterations, each of which costs O(m + n log n) time with Dijkstra's algorithm to find shortest paths on the graph with all edges that weigh no more than the maximum, testing whether there is a short enough path from 1 to N.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. But I'm still unsure about how to use binary search to find the minimum maximum edge. And doesn't dijkstra's algorithm just gives the shortest path from 1 to N?

Comment: @lostdimension Yes. We run Dijkstra on the subgraph with edges larger than the guess removed. If the shortest path is too long, then the guess was too low. If the shortest path is short enough, then the guess was just right or too high.